# Name of Supernatural episode with evil car/GPS?

Tags: episode-identification, supernatural

I remember watching this Supernatural episode like back in 2015-2016. All I remember about it was that it had an evil GPS or maybe car, and it locked a victim in the car and the GPS then displayed 666 and a pentagram, then it killed the dude I think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this *Supernatural* S10E13, **"[Halt & Catch Fire](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4344332/)"** (2015)...?

> To take his mind off of the Mark of Cain, Dean goes hunting. They track down a ghost that is killing college students through electronics and the internet.

From the [Supernatural Wiki](https://supernatural.fandom.com/wiki/Halt_%26_Catch_Fire):

> **A girl and a boy are driving down a street in Spencer, Iowa.** He says he's not sure he's okay to drive but it's nothing a little grease won't fix. **Billy asks his voice-controlled phone to direct them to the nearest Taco Town.** Janet questions the phone's directions, but he says that her phone is only 3G and that his doesn't make mistakes. Later on, Janet complains that it's cold, but Billy says that the air isn't on. **The phone leads them to a bridge that's been blocked off. Billy argues with the voice. The voice then demands Janet to get out of the truck. The truck door closes and locks Billy inside. The truck then drives forward, onto the blocked off bridge, while Janet screams.**

Comment: I am pretty sure this is it, but I remember seeing that Satanic imagery in it that this episode did not have. Maybe I am mixing 2 episodes in my mind. Regardless, thanks for the find.